# creating an image uploader with preview in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

my code does not seem to be able to pull the image from my desktop for a preview. i don't know what. All it was does, is show me a broken image. Here is the code.

javascript

```
function ajaxFileUpload(upload_field)
{
// Checking file type
var re_text = /\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif/i;
var filename = upload_field.value;
if (filename.search(re_text) == -1) {
alert("File should be either jpg or gif or jpeg or png");
upload_field.form.reset();
return false;
}
document.getElementById('picture_preview').innerHTML = '<img src="" width="10%" border="0" />';
upload_field.form.action = 'upload-picture.php';
upload_field.form.target = 'upload_iframe';
upload_field.form.submit();
upload_field.form.action = '';
upload_field.form.target = '';
return true;
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- iframe used for ajax file upload-->
<!-- debug: change it to style="display:block" -->
<iframe name="upload_iframe" id="upload_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<!-- iframe used for ajax file upload-->

<form name="pictureForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<span>Upload Picture :</span>
<input type="file" name="picture" onclick="preview()" id="picture" onchange="return ajaxFileUpload(this);" />
<span id="picture_error"></span>
<div id="picture_preview"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: The browser shows a broken image because it could not locate your image. Check your browser console, what does the error message say?

Comment: it gives me a "404 (Not found)" error

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

Javascript

```
var input = document.getElementById('image_uploader');
var uploadedImage = document.getElementById('uploaded_image');

input.addEventListener('change', onImageInput);

function onImageInput()
{
    var imageFile = input.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', onReaderComplete);
    reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
}

function onReaderComplete(e)
{
    uploadedImage.src = e.target.result;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="image_uploader"/>
<div id="picture_preview"><img id="uploaded_image"/></div>
```

After this, you can send the image data (`src`) to the server with AJAX or other stuff like that.

Comment: how would the associated HTML look like?

Comment: I have modified my answer to also contain the required HTML. You can pretty much do it in any way, as long as you have one `input` and one `img` element to work with in the JS part.